# Why do I have an off by one error?

Tags: java

In the below code, I am simply trying to count the number of times an item appears in a file. However, when I print out the keys and their values I get a count that is one more that there actually is. When I initialize `total` to 0 it fixes the problem but I am not sure why.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Problem {
   public static void main(String[] arg) {
      HashSet QID = new HashSet();
      HashMap QIDToCorrect = new HashMap();
      try {
         // Open the file that is the first command line parameter
         FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
               "C:/Users/lol/Downloads/data.csv");

         // Get the object of DataInputStream
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

         //Read File Line By Line
         String strLine;
         br.readLine(); //skip header line
         int total = 0;
         int blah = 0;
         while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] split = strLine.split(",");

            if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
               total = 1;
               QID.add(split[0]);
               QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
            } else {
               total += 1;
               QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
            }

            //System.out.println();
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? and where are you printing values?

Comment: You seem to be resetting the total to 1 every time you find a word you haven't seen before. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes my keys are items and the values are the counts. If I don't see an item then I initialize total to 1 because I just saw it for the first time.

Comment: BTW, the `readLine` BEFORE the while (i.e. below the declaration of strLine) **should be removed**.

Comment: how do i skip the first line then?

Comment: Ok. Cleaerer now. Thanks. I've updated my answer to address the main issue.

Comment: This is much more than an "off by one" error. See my answer below that steps through your code. It is a very good idea to learn how to use a debugger so you can do this kind of analysis yourself.

Comment: The crux of this problem is that you are not retrieving the total count for a word prior to updating it with it's incremented value. You could be out by a lot more than one. Just turned out to be one!

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have input where the first element of each line is as follows:

```
foo
foo
bar
foo
```

Now let's consider what your loop does with this input

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

```
        String[] split = strLine.split(",");
```

`split[0]` is the first "foo".

```
        if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
```

"foo" not added yet

```
           total = 1;
           QID.add(split[0]);
           QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
```

`total` set to `1`, "foo" added to `QID` and ("foo", 1) added to `QIDToCorrect`

```
        String[] split = strLine.split(",");
```

`split[0]` is the second "foo"

```
        if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
```

Evalutes to false, so `if` statement falls through to the `else`.

```
        } else {
           total += 1;
           QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
        }
```

`total` incremented to 2 and `QIDToCorrect` is updated to ("foo", 2).

```
        String[] split = strLine.split(",");
```

`split[0]` now contains "bar".

```
        if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
           total = 1;
           QID.add(split[0]);
           QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
```

`QID` does not contain bar, so `total` is reset to 1, "bar" is added to `QID`, and ("bar", 1) is inserted into `QIDToCorrect`.

```
        String[] split = strLine.split(",");
```

Now `split[0]` contains the *third* "foo"

```
        if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
```

"foo" has been seen before, so fall through to the `else`.

```
        } else {
           total += 1;
           QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
        }
```

`total` is incremented to 2 and `QIDToCorrect` is updated with ("foo", 2).

So your map that holds the counters thinks that there have been only *two* `foo`s. I see a problem here. Your `total` counter resets every time you see a new item. So when you call `QIDToCorrect.put()` you do not consider the number of times you have seen that item in the past. You probably need to use `QIDToCorrect.get()` in order to get the previous count of an item. This obviates the need for the `total` variable (unless you want to know the total number of all the items you have seen). Also, the `QID` HashSet is unnecessary since you can query `QIDToCorrect` if it already contains a key.

Comment: In my file, everything is clustered together. Meaning you have 11111,22222,33333.... not 1112,3111. So it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @cooldudezen It matters because your logic is incorrect. This is very likely also the source of your "off by one" error.

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm looks weird, but if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I would replace

```
if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
               total = 1;
               QID.add(split[0]);
               QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
            } else {
               total += 1;
               QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
            }
```

with

```
Integer lasttotal = (Integer)QIDToCorrect.get(split[0]);
total = 1 + lasttotal!=null ? lasttotal : 0;
QID.add(split[0]);
QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
```

That way, total would correctly count you items, even if they are not sorted... However, that does not explain your issue. Are you sure that you print the values correctly ? Did you try step-by-step debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the key before you update it ... see below:

```
if (!QID.contains(split[0])) {
   total = 1;
   QID.add(split[0]);
   QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
} else {
   total = QIDToCorrect.get(split[0]);  // RETRIEVE VALUE FOR KEY
   total += 1;
   QIDToCorrect.put(split[0], total);
}
```